# Check if parameter equals defined constant from model

Tags: php, laravel, function, switch-statement, constants

In my MeetingType model I have this constant:

```
const EXAMPLE_SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING =
[
    'Shareholders meeting',
    'Management meeting',
    'General meeting',
    'Start meeting'
];
```

In my controller I call a function from my model like this:

```
$topics = MeetingType::get_meeting_type_topics($meetingTypeName);
```

Where `$meetingTypeName` equals 'Shareholders meeting'.

How do I check in my function/switch if the passed parameter matches my constant array? This is the function I am talking about:

```
/**
 * Define and return MeetingType Topics. 
 *
 * @param string $meetingTypeName
 * @return array
 */
public static function get_meeting_type_topics($meetingTypeName)
{
    switch (MeetingType::EXAMPLE_SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING) {
        case 'Shareholders meeting':
            $topics = [
                'Opening',
            ];
            break;
        case 'Management meeting':
            $topics = [
                'Aanwezigen / afwezigen',
            ];
            break;
        case 'General meeting':
            $topics = [
                'Opening',
            ];
            break;
        case 'Start meeting':
            $topics = [
                "Uitleg van deze vergadering",
            ];
            break;
    }

    return $topics;
}
```

Comment: in_array($meetingTypeName,MeetingType::EXAMPLE_SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING). it will return you true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with

```php
class MeetingEntity {
// ...
  const SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING = 0;
  const MANAGEMENT_MEETING = 1;
  const GENERAL_MEETING = 2;
  const START_MEETING = 3;

  const MEETINGS_TYPES =
  [
    0 => self::SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING,
    1 => self::MANAGEMENT_MEETING,
    2 => self::GENERAL_MEETING,
    3 => self::START_MEETING,
  ];
// ...
```

For reasons that I'm somewhat used to this pattern. It is very helpful especially, where keys are not numbers but words.

Than you can go with switches with something simple:

```php
switch($aMeetingType) {
    case MeetingEntity::SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING:
      // ....
      break;
```

or a bit more safe:

```php
if (array_key_exists($aMeetingType, MeetingEntity::MEETING_TYPES)) {
    switch(MeetingEntity::MEETING_TYPES[$aMeetingType]) {
        case MeetingEntity::SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING:
            // ...
            break;
    }
} else { // throw
```

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine your `const EXAMPLE_SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING`  to

```
const EXAMPLE_SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING =
[
    'Shareholders meeting' => 'Opening',
    'Management meeting' => 'Aanwezigen / afwezigen',
    'General meeting' => 'Opening',
    'Start meeting' => "Uitleg van deze vergadering",
];
```

And in your function return something like:

```
public static function get_meeting_type_topics($meetingTypeName)
{
    return MeetingType::EXAMPLE_SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING[$meetingTypeName];
}
```

Comment: It is a solution in given case, but it is certainly not a clean one. You are mixing here constants, which should keep logic switches with translations.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the approach of @u_mulder. But here it is with some improvement:

```
public static function get_meeting_type_topics($meetingTypeName)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($meeetingName, MeetingType::EXAMPLE_SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING)) {
        return 'Not handled meeting';
    }
    return MeetingType::EXAMPLE_SHAREHOLDERS_MEETING[$meetingTypeName];
}
```